# SQL Server : CASE and concatenate string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to know how I can output concatenated string from multiple SQL `CASE` expressions.

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    u.UserId, 
    FirstName,
    CASE u.access_b
       WHEN '5000' THEN 'Active'
       ELSE ''
    END AS B,
    CASE u.access_l
       WHEN '2199-12-31' THEN 'Active'
       ELSE ''
    END AS LK
FROM 
    Users u
JOIN
    userGroupMembership ugm ON u.userId = ugm.userId
JOIN
    usergroup ug ON ug.usergroupId = ugm.usergroupId
WHERE 
    ug.usergroupId = 1220 
    AND (u.primaryType = 1 or u.primaryType = 2)
```

I'm getting this:

[image]

So instead of the two columns B and LK, I want to introduce a new column which will be called Access Level, and if B is Active or LK is active, add B or LK depending for each program. For example, if B only is active, output for 'Access Level' column will be B, if both programs are active then output will be 'B, LK', if LK is active only, the column will have vakue of LK.

What are my options to concatenate a column value from multiple case queries?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I don't think this is possible without a subquery. I assume you don't want to go that way, right?

Comment: Any approach will work as long as I'll be able to get the data I need in the right way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
SELECT T.*,
       CASE WHEN B = 'Active' AND LK = 'Active' THEN 'B, LK'
            WHEN B = 'Active' THEN 'B'
            WHEN LK = 'Active' THEN 'LK'
            ELSE ''
            END AS [Access Level]
FROM
(
    SELECT u.UserId, 
           FirstName,
           case u.access_b
           When '5000' then 'Active'
           Else ''
           End as B,
           case u.access_l
           when '2199-12-31' then 'Active'
           else ''
           end as LK
    FROM Users u
    join userGroupMembership ugm ON u.userId = ugm.userId
    join usergroup ug ON ug.usergroupId = ugm.usergroupId
    WHERE ug.usergroupId = 1220 and (u.primaryType = 1 or u.primaryType = 2)
) T
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a third CASE expression that checks the combinations you describe and assigns the appropriate value.  In pseudocode:

```
CASE 
  WHEN {B is active} AND {LK is active} THEN 'B, LK'
  WHEN {B is active} THEN 'B'
  WHEN {LK is active} THEN 'LK'
  ELSE ''
END
```

CASE expressions are evaluated in order from top to bottom and resolve to the first WHEN condition that is met, so if both B and LK are active, then the first condition will be met, the first result will be returned, and it won't matter that the other two conditions are also both true.

Comment: I don't think that will work, I'm getting error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 48
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'is'.

Comment: This is not cut-and-paste code, this is pseudo-code.   You need to replace the parts in the braces with the actual code from your query.

Comment: Can you please write the actual code, I will really appreciate that. Thanks